# How to get XMLHttpRequest responseText while using .bind in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

This is what I would LIKE to do:

```
response: string;
sendCreateInvoice(invoice, job){
  let url = 'assets/php/myScript.php';
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      this.response = this.responseText;
    };
  };
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(invoice);
}
```

so I THINK I need to use `.bind(this)` but when I do that I can't seem to access `this.responseText` anymore. I tried like this:

```
response: string;
sendCreateInvoice(invoice, job){
  let url = 'assets/php/myScript.php';
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      this.response = this.responseText;
    };
  }.bind(this);
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(invoice);
}
```

And I tried `this.xmlhttp.responseText` and `xmlhttp.responseText` but no luck. Where am I going wrong? How can I save the `responseText` to `response`?

==================

Working code:

```
response: string;
sendCreateInvoice(){
  let url = 'assets/php/myScript.php';
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      this.response = xmlhttp..responseText;
    };
  };
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(invoice);
}
```

Comment: `xmlhttp.responseText` should have worked. Maybe you forgot `xmlhttp.readyState` and `xmlhttp.status`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xmlhttp` to refer to the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

And the calls to `open()` and `send()` need to be outside the callback function.

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      this.response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
  }.bind(this);
```

Also, instead of `.bind(this)`, you can use an arrow function.

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      this.response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
  };
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(invoice);
```

Arrow functions treat `this` as a normal lexical variable.

Comment: It worked! The arrow function did the trick. I don't know why. I didn't try the `that` method because I didn't like the extra step :) Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `bind` just store the value of `this` in a variable outside the function, because you're using `this` as the request inside the function! Like this:

```
response: string;
sendCreateInvoice(invoice, job){
  var that = this; // <<<< store it here

  let url = 'assets/php/myScript.php';
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      that.response = this.responseText;
  //  ^^^^ use it here
    };
  };

  // these two lines should be outside of the callback of the event listener
  xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send(invoice);
}
```

Comment: yes, the open and send were just a typo, I'll edit that. Thanks for the response!